# No signal to monitor after cloning M.2 SSD boot drive

Tags: windows-10, boot, disk-cloning

My machine was running Win 10 just fine but its OS drive was getting full so I cloned it to another M.2. SSD using the latest version of Macrium Reflect.

(Because the new drive is larger, I did move around the partitions of the new drive so that the main partition is next to the empty space that I plan to reclaim.)

Now there is no signal to my monitor. I tried different inputs, different GPUs, removed and put back the RAM. Nothing has worked. What should I do now besides giving up and putting the old drive back?

Comment: Windows 10 is typically in UEFI mode so you also need to clone the ESP. Did you?

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia I cloned every partition of the original drive. To be honest, I'm still now sure what went wrong. The system wouldn't boot either when I put the original drive back. Then I changed the CMOS battery and it would boot but Windows wouldn't start. So what I did in the end: put the new drive back (since the old drive was problematic anyway), boot, reset the OS (because Windows wouldn't start with the new drive either), reinstall programs, and now migrate personal data from old drive. I will delete this post soon within a day but I'd like to thank you for the comment.